# Can't access an associated type

Tags: rust

I have a type that is defined as an associated type of a trait bound on another associated type. For some reason, the compiler refuses to find it.

```rust
trait B {
    type A;
}

trait C {
    type X: B;
    fn foo(&self) -> &Self::X::A;
}
```

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
 --> src/lib.rs:7:23
  |
7 |     fn foo(&self) -> &Self::X::A;
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<<Self as C>::X as Trait>::A`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use fully qualified syntax for traits:

```rust
trait B {
    type A;
}

trait C {
    type X: B;
    fn foo(&self) -> &<Self::X as B>::A;
}
```

[Explanation of this issue from lcnr on the Rust Zulip](https://rust-lang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/122651-general/topic/Beginner.3A.20Associated.20type.20question/near/248828115):

> iirc the reason that `Type::Assoc1::Assoc2` does not work but instead needs `<Type::Assoc1 as Trait>::Assoc2` is that we (currently) figure out which trait an associated type belongs to during name resolution, which happens quite early during compilation. That means that we can't yet reason about which traits are implemented and so on without some hacks.
>
> So even though `Assoc2` might be unambiguous we still require explicit annotations by the user